# What does Makefile mean in cuda common.mk

Tags: cuda, makefile

I'm new to CUDA, recently I want to compile my mpi+cuda program, so I use the common.mk in CUDA SDK. I just can't understand this line in common.mk

```
$(TARGET): makedirectories $(OBJS) $(CUBINS) $(PTXBINS) Makefile   //line 447
```

makedirectories is a target and can be a prerequisite, but what does Makefile mean?

Comment: It looks like they're listing the Makefile itself as a dependency. But if it's named "common.mk", that's not going to work very well. I think you're probably supposed to have your own Makefile (that maybe includes the common.mk or something)

Answer (score 1):

That line tells Make to rebuild target in case when Makefile gets modified.

It is not a reliable way to track rule/prerequisite changes (because of environment variables, inclusion of other makefiles, etc.), but it works in most cases.